# How to print output of ruby function to a file

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line

I have written a program in ruby. The output correspondng to which is really long, a couple of thousand lines.

Is there a way I can write this output to a file and not in the shell, because the shell allows you to scroll up only till a certain point? I know that I can use `file.puts` in place of `puts`. But, I want to know if there is a command using which I can achieve this without making changes in the program? For shell scripts we can do `script.sh > output.txt`. Similarly for a shell command as well. But what about a ruby program? It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: That should do it. How is it not working?

Comment: You could change the value of `$stdout`.  `puts` uses `$stdout`, not `STDOUT`...  But I'm not sure what you're asking for...

Comment: use this `File.open("out.txt", 'OPTION') {|f| f.write("write your stuff here") }`

Comment: We need to see the code that you're asking about. It's an easy task, but we can write code that won't fit into yours easily so working from where you are is better than you trying to shoehorn in what we come up with. Besides, Stack Overflow expects you to show some effort. As is, you're just asking about code, not showing any, so please help us to help you.

Comment: @screenmutt : Actually the program prompts for a user input. on typing `./program.rb > output.txt`. The program terminates if I press enter, its not prompting for user input

Comment: @nish What is the aversion to changing the code?

Comment: The question needs to explain what doesn't work.  "doesn't seem to be working" doesn't tell us anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `./program.rb > output.txt` redirects the output *as well as* the prompts for input into the text file, so you can't see what you're doing. You have several options:

1. Use `STDERR.puts` to prompt for input, so it doesn't get caught by the redirection. This is my preferred method.
2. Use `ARGV` to pass input to your program. This is a good option if you think the program isn't too hard to use without prompts.
3. Use `File.open` to create an output file and write to it directly. Sometimes this is the most sensible option, but usually you want to do one of the first two.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for a simple puts output:

foo.rb:

```
foo = gets.chomp
puts "Input was: " + foo
```

Terminal:

```
ruby foo.rb > test.txt
```

Comment: Your program needs to accept user input, see the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is asking for input, maybe you can change your program to accept input from the command line (ARGV[0] etc), then redirect the output to a file :

```
ruby myprogram > out.txt
```